# Where can I clear non-razor view engines in a Web Pages site?

Tags: asp.net, razor, webforms, webmatrix, global-asax

It is recommended when using the Razor View Engine to unload any others (such as Web forms) in Global.asax like so:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

But Razor 2 web sites do not have a Global.asax file, so where I can accomplish this there?

Comment: As far as I know only ASP.NET MVC uses view engines. If you are using the WebPages framework in Webmatrix then you don't have this problem. Because the only "view engine" is razor...

Comment: Beauty! (Strange Brew)